# easy_install networkx

Tags: macos, easy-install, networkx

Am using Mac OS X.  I installed networkx by entering easy_install networkx in the Terminal.  The terminal says Finished processing dependencies for networkx.  However when I enter import networkx into the python shell, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx
ImportError: No module named networkx
```

So I did it again and got back

networkx 1.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
What can I do to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to install with pip not with easy_install. 
I had used macport to install networkx once, even if i can see that i installed it, i couldn't use networkx and i got some errors. When i check the problem, accidentally i learned that using pip is better. I tried with pip and now I'm using networkx without any problem. By the way I'm using MacOS X also.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to convince easy_install to work on Mac OS X either.

Fortunately, there is an easy solution to installing NetworkX on Mac OS X.

1. download and uncompress the NetworkX 1.6 files from here: http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/networkx/
2. cd to the uncompressed networkx folder
3. type this: sudo python ./setup.py install

After doing this, check whether you can import networkx in Python.

I think you've already done step 1; I just mentioned it for the sake of other readers.